# Bind to specific AncestorType, skipping derived types

Tags: wpf, data-binding, relativesource

I'm using a DevExpress `LayoutGroup`, which constructs multiple children I have no influence on. The `LayoutGroup` has an `IsCollapsible` property, which, when true, adds a button to the group's header and the functionality of collapsing/expanding the group's content.

The constructed visual tree looks like this:

```
[LayoutControl]
  CollapsibleNavigationGroup [LayoutGroup]
    [GroupBox]
      [Container]
        BorderElement [Border]
          [LayoutControl]
            TitleElement [Container]
              TitleContent [LayoutControl]
```

This usually only works when clicking the button itself but I extended the functionality to clicking the header. Now, if the `GroupBox` is collapsible I want the cursor to change to a hand when hovering above the header, so I did this in its template:

```
<dxlc:LayoutControl x:Name="TitleContent"
                    Cursor="{Binding IsCollapsible, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type dxlc:LayoutGroup}}, Converter={StaticResource BoolToCursorConverter}}">
```

However, `LayoutControl` is derived from `LayoutGroup` and thus FindAncestor does not actually find my CollapsibleNavigationGroup but the element's grand-parent, the nameless `LayoutControl`. Now I wonder, is there any way to tell the relative source binding to actually look for this exact type and ignore any derived types?

Comment: Is giving it a name, and referring to it that way, not working?

Comment: I would rather avoid it as that name is just randomly chosen to see whether the correct LayoutGroup is bound. I'd prefer to solely use the IsCollapsible property to determine whether the LayoutGroup is collapsible so we won't have to take care of naming every future LayoutGroup the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now I wonder, is there any way to tell the relative source binding to actually look for this exact type and ignore any derived types?

No, there isn't. But you can set the `AncestorLevel` property to `2` to skip the first ancestor of the type specified by the `AncestorType` property, e.g.:

```
<dxlc:LayoutControl ... Cursor="{Binding IsCollapsible, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, 
                        AncestorType={x:Type dxlc:LayoutGroup}, 
                        AncestorLevel=2}, Converter={StaticResource BoolToCursorConverter}}">
```

Comment: I've seen the AncestorLevel option but my mind was numb and couldn't connect the two. This has worked nicely, thanks.